# ruby on rails remote database connection MySQL The 'InnoDB' feature is disabled error

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to remotely connect to a MySQL database using ruby on rails.

In my database.yml:

```
development:
 adapter: mysql
 database: peer
 host: host
 port: 3306
 username: root
 password: password
```

I then go to do a rake db:migrate and get this error

```
Mysql::Error: The 'InnoDB' feature is disabled; you need MySQL built with 'InnoDB' to have it working: CREATE TABLE `schema_migrations` (`version` varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Now after some searching, I found that this was an error on Windows Servers with MySQL and I needed to go into the my.ini file and comment out skip-innodb. When I went to do that however, that line wasn't in that file but in a different one named "my-innodb-heavy-4g.ini"

I found the command in the line, but it was already commented out. And now I am at a loss on what to do next.

This application is going to be connected to multiple databases as well, I just wanted to see if I could connect to the remote one first.

Comment: Please post OS version, MySQL version, how have you installed it (binary install)
This is not a Rails issue

Comment: Windows Server 2008. See below for other information. I'm assuming they installed it with the installation package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop MySQL, rename my.ini to something else, rename "my-innodb-heavy-4g.ini" to my.ini, restart MySQL. Assuming, of course, that your MySQL server was built with InnoDB in the first place.

**Edit**: it appears that the OP is using a server deliberately built without InnoDB support. See e.g. [here](http://www.bits-pilani.ac.in:12360/courses/SDETC103/mySQL/manual.html), a 5.0 reference manual, under section "2.3.2. Enterprise Server Distribution Types":

- This section does not apply to MySQL 
  Community Server users.

  ...

  mysql-classic: Released under a commercial license, does not include 
  InnoDB.

...and the poster now says their server is indeed a 5.0 "mysql-classic".

So, it appears that the only way to use InnoDB under these conditions is to upgrade the server to something more functional (and ideally a bit more recent, but that's no big deal).

Comment: Tried this, didn't work. I couldn't restart the service after I renamed the file. I also added the InnoDB commands into the my.ini file and got an error when trying to start the service with the new commands as well.

Comment: Looks like you may have a MySQL binary that was built without any support for InnoDB -- exactly what version is it and where did you get it from?

Comment: Server Info:
MySQL 5.0.58-classic-nt-log via TCP/IP

Client Info:
MySQL Client Version 5.1.11

Unfortunately I can't tell you where I got it from. It's the company database and my boss isn't in today.

Comment: The 5.whatever numbers are fine, InnoDB has been in from well before then; and the client is not relevant. Your problem is w/your specific server build, let me edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for all your help. We were able to upgrade without any problems.